# Sonarqube setup in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, sonarqube, ubuntu-18.04

Trying to setup Sonarqube in Ubuntu 18.04 (on Ec2) using mysql, Went thru this [digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-ensure-code-quality-with-sonarqube-on-ubuntu-18-04)

But after all that `sudo service sonarqube start`  errors out:

`ubuntu@ip-:/opt/sonarqube$ sudo service sonarqube start`

```
Job for sonarqube.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status sonarqube.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

`ubuntu@ip-:/opt/sonarqube$ systemctl status sonarqube.service`

```
sonarqube.service - SonarQube service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonarqube.service; disabled; vendor prese
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-10-04 16:45:33 UTC; 1min 43
  Process: 11036 ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start (code=

Oct 04 16:45:32 ip-172-31-41-243 systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Control process
Oct 04 16:45:32 ip-172-31-41-243 systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Failed with resu
Oct 04 16:45:32 ip-172-31-41-243 systemd[1]: Failed to start SonarQube service.
Oct 04 16:45:33 ip-172-31-41-243 systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Service hold-off
Oct 04 16:45:33 ip-172-31-41-243 systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Scheduled restar
Oct 04 16:45:33 ip-172-31-41-243 systemd[1]: Stopped SonarQube service.
Oct 04 16:45:33 ip-172-31-41-243 systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Start request re
Oct 04 16:45:33 ip-172-31-41-243 systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Failed with resu
Oct 04 16:45:33 ip-172-31-41-243 systemd[1]: Failed to start SonarQube service.
```

Tried another tutorial and with different version of sonarqube and different DB - same result. Is there a resource requirement (memory) for sonarqube - I am deploying on EC2 t2.micro - 8GB - **assuming that should be enough?**

Tried `/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start` this gives error:

**Syntax error**: newline unexpected (expecting ")").   I had Not edited the sonar.sh file

**SonarQube Docker**
Tried going [Docker route](https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/) - did not work.
Connection refused on port 9000. I have TCP/9000 opened in the Security Group and NACL is all open.
`http://IP:9000` This `site can’t be reached x.x.x.x refused to connect`

Comment: can you please show sonaqube logs?? The ones here are cutted on the right, and no error code can be read. do you have a /var/log/sonarqube.log or similar?? did you tried to activate deeper logs??

Comment: Maybe you can try with an official Sonarqube docker (it comes packaged with all you need)

Comment: @Alejandro Teixeira - could not find any log file in the system at all - sonarqube.log or sonarqube.logs

Comment: Check this @Sam-T https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/system-info/ -> you may configure DEBUG mode and find the location for log files.

Comment: you can also try to run `/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start` and try to see the logs in the console

Comment: Have you used it yet?? if you are not updating, I strongly reccomend you to install a docker image. It's just 5 minutes, and if you want I can help you with it. Are you using ubuntu under windows?? or is it a fresh ubuntu? I had also problems with ubuntu, and with docker image I had no problem (on windows at least). On linux should be easy too.

I mean: Sonarqube needs a database, and other services that you should install before and that must be up to allow sonarqube to run. In the docker image, all is together packed and ready-to-use

Comment: @Alejandro - As mentioned in my 1st post I am using (fresh ubuntu) on AWS. If you can share docker setup instructions - i can try using that. I will use AWS/Ubuntu

Comment: @Alejandro - tried /opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start  this gives error ;  Syntax error: newline unexpected (expecting ")").  I had Not edited the sonar.sh file

Comment: ummmm.... it should work.... and it seems you created a newline inside "start.sh" I strongly reccomend you to install sonarqube in just a minute

Comment: 1.- Installing docker on ubuntu -> https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04 (use the option 2) - Install from official repository

2.-  Here is Sonarqube Docker image. You just need to use "docker pull sonarqube" when docker is installed, an docker will download it.  The instructions to run are on https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/

Comment: Started docker install *using Option 2* - fails on Step-3   ~$ `curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gp  g | sudo apt-key add –`
   `gpg: can't open '–'`:  **No such file or directory**

Comment: You have an space on `gp g`

Comment: No, no gap - somehow the format here is showing incorrectly.   `curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add –`       `gpg: can't open '–':` **No such file or directory**

Comment: The problem here was upper case dash `–` vs lowercase dash `-` . I am just cutting and pasting- it is wrong in the document as upper case. So with correct lower case dash  `-`  the command works as expected.  All these things somehow turn in into big research/debug projects.

Comment: oh... add your answer here if you can!!

Comment: I was able to start the sonar dockerqube container.  `sudo docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 sonarqube`
ccd99b0bf92b4fb3a5a18a5fc61943d09e00740f15e68142e559800d582fda1e
   But when I try connect using browser from another machine : **refused to connect**.  I do have `port 9000/TCP opened inbound`.

Comment: `http://IP:9000`  This site can’t be reached   `x.x.x.x refused to connect`

Comment: can you create a new answer to your own question???

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Mine was caused by an extra white space in the systemctl service config file. I suggest you check properly, or delete and recreate the service file. More carefully this time.